# When using Vue List Rendering, how can you use v-if to check if items are in an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using `v-if` to conditionally render a list of cafes. However, I only want it to list items based on whether a drink item is listed in an array.

For example, here is a list of cafes, for which I would like it to show only cafes which serve tea. Can this be done?

HTML;

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
      <li v-for="cafe in cafes" v-if="drinks == 'drinks('tea')'">
         <h2>{{cafe.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{cafe.location}}</p>
        <span v-for="drinks in cafe.drinks">
            {{drinks}}
        </span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then my script is as follows;

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            cafes: [
              { 
                name: 'The Black Cup Cafe',
                location: 'Australia',
                drinks: ['tea', 'coffee', 'Lemonade']
              },
              { 
                name: 'Rest Cafe bar',
                location: 'Brazil',
                drinks: ['tea', 'coffee', 'Coke']
              }              
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can use includes to check that tea in drinks array or not.

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
      <li v-for="cafe in cafes" v-if="cafe.drinks.includes('tea')">
         <h2>{{cafe.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{cafe.location}}</p>
        <span v-for="drinks in cafe.drinks">
            {{drinks}}
        </span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You are a genius!

Comment: vue.js doesnt recommend to use `v-if` with `v-for`. They say to use computed properties for such a usecase

Answer (score 1):

just add some condition：cafe.drinks.includes('tea')

```
<div id="app">
   <ul>
      <template v-for="cafe in cafes" >
        <li :key="index" v-if="cafe.drinks.includes('tea')">
          <h2>{{cafe.name}}</h2>
          <p>{{cafe.location}}</p>
          <span v-for="drinks in cafe.drinks">
            {{drinks}}
          </span>
       </li>
     </template>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html), Note that it’s not recommended to use v-if and v-for together. Refer to style guide for details